# Y-axis markers are multiples of odd numbers

Tags: highcharts, axis-labels

I have a small team of developers working for me to graph some medical data. They have come back with no resolution. Hopefully someone here can help.

When charting a series the y-axis multiples are not the default highchart multiples. For example in highcharts when I plot the below code, the y-axis labels are 0,250,500,750,1000,1250.

However, when I view the graph in my application I get the following: 0,95,190,285,380,475,570,665,760,855,950. See image attached.[Odd intervals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEmHy.png)

The only other information I can provide is that the container size is relative, and when I change the size of the window, the index values change. That would suggest to me that they are not hard-coded to be a fixed multiple.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

title: {
    text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
},

yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Number of Employees'
    }
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
},

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointStart: 2010
    }
},

series: [ {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [0,100,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024]
}]

});
```

Comment: There a few options which allow to control ticks positions - tickInterval, tickPositions, tickPixelInterval, tickPositioner - see axis API http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval. Do you want the ticks to have fixed value? If so, you should use tickPositions or tickPositioner - https://jsfiddle.net/m6Lqp95m/

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

So a solution is below. Basically, it scans the array for a multiple that is greater than the ideal divider count (in this example 10). It then uses that as the desired interval.

```
function returnInterval(){
var intervalArray = 
[.0001,.001,.01,.1,1,2,5,10,20,50,100,250,500,1000,5000,10000]
var min = .0012 //min from series below
var max = .1001 //max from series below
var idealDivider = (max - min)/10 //where 10 is the number of desired markers

for(var i=0; i<intervalArray.length; i++) {
    if (intervalArray[i] >= idealDivider) return intervalArray[i];
}
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
yAxis:{

    tickInterval:  returnInterval()
},
series: [{
    data: [.0012,.0213,.0123,.0532,.042,.009942,.1001]
}]});
```